# odoo t-raw / argument inside t-if condition

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I'm trying inside Odoo V12, that if the user has a signature, this should be printed. If not, just a static text should be used.
I have tried this:

```
<div>
    <p t-if="record.user_id and record.user_id.signature">
        t-raw="record.user_id.signature"</p>
    <p t-else="">just the company name</p>
/div>
```

But this will just end with, that the "t-raw="record.user_id.signature" as text is shown.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is HTML code itself, so it shouldn't be in a `p` tag. Just try to use the `t` tag and give a `p` to your `else`:

```xml
<div>
    <t t-if="record.user_id.signature" t-raw="record.user_id.signature" />
    <t t-else=""><p>just the company name</p></t>
</div>
```

You probably have to expand the if condition because emptying the signature or any HTML field in Odoo will fill the field with `<p><br></p>` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working if there is a signature available. If there is no signature set it will be just blank, is this what you mentioned regarding expanding the if condition?

Comment: @L.Writer yes because Odoo is filling the provided HTML in the answer in an "empty" HTML field.